# Executing Raw sql with Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The below I can have a condition to execute view/table, which would load into AccountDataModel class.

```
 dbcontext.AccountDataModel.FromSql($"select * from account where id=123").FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I retrieve without using a class model, if I want to retrieve just 1 or 2 columns

example: select name from account where id=123

Do I always need a class model?

Answer (score 2):

ADO.NET works in EFCore =)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;

    public void ExampleMethod(DbContext context)
    {
        SomeObjectResult result = null;
        DbCommand cmd = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select C.ID, C.CarModelID as ModelID, C.VIN, C.RegNumber,cast(C.CountValue as int) as Course,A.BrandID from   A inner join C on A.ID = C.KeyID  Where A.ID = @appID";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@appID", appointmentID));
        if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
        }
        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                result = new SomeObjectResult()
                {
                    BrandID = (int)reader["BrandID"],
                    Course = (int)reader["Course"],
                    ID = (int)reader["ID"],
                    ModelID = (int?)reader["ModelID"],
                    RegNumber = (string)reader["RegNumber"],
                    VIN = (string)reader["VIN"]
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. like this :

```
var account = dbcontext.AccountDataModel.FromSql(@"select a.id, a.name from account a where a.id=123");
```

source : [FromSql for non entity type](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/query-types#fromsql)

Comment: I dont want to use AccoutDataModel, I know i can map from sql to my POCO class (like I mentioned in the example) I want to retrieve a column example 'name' to var name = dbcontext.XXXX....

Comment: you mean something like that : https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#leveraging-ado.net-via-the-context.database-property ? (section Leveraging ADO.NET via the Context.Database property)

Answer (score 0):

This queries the database

```
 var name = dbcontext.GetDBConnection().Query("select name from account where id=123").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Ben Updated answer

Comment: I am unable to get instance GetDbConnection() and if I use dbcontext.Database.GetDbConnection() then Query(..) not found. Do i need to install NuGet package?